# Cocoapods : Library Not found

Tags: ios, compiler-errors, xcode6, cocoapods

I am trying to run a Cocoapods project and getting the following error

[image: Library Not Found for -lAttributedMarkdown]

I tried to `pod deintegrate` and then `pod install` but it's still there.
I also tried removing the `pod.debug.xcconfig` file from `Project->Info->Configuration` and then `pod install` but nothing.

`pod.debug.xcconfig` generated by `pod install` contain path like `${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/AttributedMarkdown`

[image: Here is the xcconfig file]

but I can't find `'Headers/Public'` in Project Navigator
[image]

Comment: To clarify…

Do you mean you are trying to run an Xcode project with pods installed?

Are you definitely opening the 'App.xcworkspace' file and not the Xcode project file?

Comment: @ChrisChinchilla I am using xcworkspace only, but the path created in xcconfig file is not in the project navigator. Headers/Public

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**First line of defense**: (Quit Xcode first, which is part of the strategy) :

```
rm -rf Pods/ Podfile.lock ; pod install
```

**Defensive approach**: verify your Podfile. Is it coherent? How about your tools versions? What happens if you create a new Podfile with `pod init`? Do you have all targets as expected?

**Drastic measure**:
Rebuild **xcworkspace** entirely:

1. quit Xcode
2. mv project.xcworkspace to a backup location
3. `sudo gem install cocoapods` (get latest)
4. `rm -rf Pods/ Podfile.lock ; pod install`

---

**Note:**

Notice the use of `rm -rf Pods/ Podfile.lock ; pod install` instead of `pod update`.

Comment: Thanks, some of the targets were missing, I've to edit the Schema.

Comment: So a new `pod init` is what helped in figuring it out?

Comment: Hi @NaveenNautiyal, do you remember what schema you edited, as I have the same error with multiple targets, can you help?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're building the same archs in `Pods` and the target. I was able to resolve it by going to the `Pods` project and setting `Build Active Architecture Only` to *No* for all builds/configs. No need to execute any commands outside of Xcode.